# change div scroll height based on other elements in css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a div element that wraps items in it

```
<div id="#wrapper" style="overflow: scroll; max-height: 100%;">
  <ul> 
    <!--lots of li's go here.
      When an li is clicked, "#details" pop from below.
    -->
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="#detils" style="display:none; height:30%;">item details</div>
```

Since there might be lots of items, the div has:

```css
max-height: 100%;
```

When an item is clicked, details section should pop from below.
Its height is **30%**.

How can I make the div wrapper scrollbar height automatically adapt to the new situation in **CSS only**. In other words: its height should now change to 100%-70%=30%

Comment: Have you tried removing the height specification?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @EvanNudd
when I remove height property, the scrollbar doesn't appear on the div: the div simply becomes too large, and not limited by screen height

Comment: Ok was just checking, that's how i've solved similar issues, like @alireza said can you please provide a jsfiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: @MoneerOmar Your jsfiddle is not completed, please insert your jquery there.

Comment: @alirezasafian The whole point here is not to use jquery or javascript to achieve this. I updated the fiddle to make it clearer. http://jsfiddle.net/j935w787/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class which has `height:30;` when the item is clicked.

I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/j935w787/2/) can help you.

Comment: thanks @alireza. it's good for me, although I thought there should be some CSS only logic that controls this in some way